# How to use dynamic condition with $match

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I want to match data with specific Id each time 
NB: item = ['id1','id2']

```
 let logs = await Promise.all(
  tpes.map(async (item) => {
    return await this.logModel.aggregate([
      {$match:{terminalId:item}},
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$outcome',
          value: {
            $sum: 1,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          name: '$_id',
          value: 1,
          _id: 0,
        },
      },
    ]);
  }),
);
console.log('logs', logs);
return logs.flat();
```

}
I got no output , I'm very confused , Any solution please or an alternatives ?

Comment: Please add some sample documents and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a loop here - if you want to match all records where `terminalId` is either `id1` or `id2`, you can use the `$in` [operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
const terminalIds = ["id1", "id2"];

const result = await this.logModel.aggregate([
      {$match:{terminalId:{$in: terminalIds}}},
  // ... rest of your code
```

Comment: Not the result of one of them , I want both means ==> match with first index and second index together I hope you reply

Answer (score 0):

your code is right
but issue might be with terminalIds
if they are object id type then you have to pass as object id

```
 let logs = await Promise.all(
 tpes.map(async (item) => {
 return await this.logModel.aggregate([
   {$match:{terminalId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item)}},
 // ... rest of your code
```